# ng-repeat in string with /n

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to make a ng-repeat on the source below, before'm dealing with commas.

My intention is to make a directive, and insert in checkboxes.

I need to turn this into a JSON? How?

```
Teste1\nTeste2\nTeste3\nTeste4\nTeste5
```

Directive:

```
.directive('fieldCreate', function($compile, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        require  : 'ngModel',
        replace  : true,
        template : '<ng-include src="getTemplateUrl()"/>',
        scope    : {
            'field': '=',
            'model': '=ngModel'
        },
        controller: function($scope) {

            $scope.field.opts = $scope.field.opts.split(/\n/);

            $scope.getTemplateUrl = function() {
                if ($scope.field.type == "input")    return "partials/fields/show/input.html";
                if ($scope.field.type == "textarea") return "partials/fields/show/textarea.html";
                if ($scope.field.type == "checkbox") return "partials/fields/show/checkbox.html";
            };


        }
    };

});
```

Comment: What about split your string with "\n" and then handle it as an array?

Comment: json accepts \n. If your server send "field":"text\nwith\nnew\nlines", your text will come with new lines. But, of course, html will to ignore new lines on blocks other than <pre> blocks.

Comment: with this code? $scope.field.opts = $scope.field.opts.replace(/\n/g, ',');

Comment: my server returns: "opts": "Teste1\nTeste2\nTeste3\nTeste4\nTeste5"

Comment: Yes @jao thats what i mean, and thanks to complete the answer

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo this returns = ["Teste1", "Teste2", "Teste3", "Teste4", "Teste5"]

Comment: That is an array, and you can apply ng repeat without problem

Comment: i put the directive code, for help others

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo how i accept your answer?